# mouse event between render and useEffect

Tags: reactjs, react-hooks

Here is code example: [codesandbox](https://codesandbox.io/s/between-render-and-useeffect-tzpv56?file=/src/index.js)

After I click `companyB` button, Child component will re-render. After re-render, it will run useEffect.

My question is: is it possible to click `companyA1` between the time Child runs re-render and useEffect and hence see console outputs as `companyB companyA1` ?

```
function Child({ company }) {
  const [list, setList] = useState([]);

  useEffect(() => {
    setList([]);
    setTimeout(() => {
      setList([{ id: company + "1" }]);
    }, 500);
  }, [company]);

  const handleClick = (company, item) => {
    console.log(company, item.id);
  };

  return (
    <div style={{ marginTop: "16px" }}>
      {list.map((item) => (
        <button key={item.id} onClick={() => handleClick(company, item)}>{item.id}</button>
      ))}
    </div>
  );
}
```

My opinion is that it's possible but I can't prove it.

Comment: Technically it should be possible, I guess, but for that your browser/computer would have to be under so much load that I'd expect the cursor to also be affected/lagging. So, I don't think that this is an issue. What's the problem? Why are you asking?

Comment: I'm asking because I want to avoid output `companyB companyA1`. `companyA` and `companyB` shold be isolated. I know that it's unlikely to happen in common scenarios. But it's still a bug, isn't it?  @Thomas

Comment: No, you heard me wrong there, it's not unlikely, it is impossible in common scenarios and *highly* unlikely even in rare scenarios. But if you're that paranoid about it, add a `key` like `<Child key={company} company={company} />`

Comment: If the possibility exists, then it's a bug in my opinion. Your fix (or improvment) makes sense to me. I think `useLayoutEffect` could also do the job.

Comment: Correction: `useLayoutEffect` will not fix the problem.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Just remove 2nd line inside the `useEffect`

```
useEffect(() => {
    // setList([]);
    setTimeout(() => {
        setList([{ id: company + '1' }]);
    }, 1000); // i have changed this to 1000 because it is easy to test
}, [company]);
```

First I clicked on **companyB**, then **companyA1** (before 1 second).
I got that output you want

Comment: If you keep `setList([])`, not commenting it out, is it still possible(no matter how tiny the possibility is) to see output `companyB companyA1`?

Comment: `setList([])` does empty the list. So you don't have a button list to click.